Не получается сделать пегинацию, фильтруя выдачу custom post type ajax в в вродпрес
помогите с вопросом не понимаю как исправить и что не так.
Делаю ajax фильтр постов, не получается сделать пагинацию.
Вопрос видимо в выдаче custom post type и атрибутах функции.
function posts_filters(){

 $args = array(
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => $_POST['date'],
   'posts_per_page' => 10,
   'paged' => $paged,


 );

 if( isset( $_POST['categoryfilter'] ) )

  $args['tax_query'] = array(
  array(
  

   'taxonomy' => 'mebel_post_type',
   'field' => 'id',
   'terms' => $_POST['categoryfilter']
  )
 );

 $query = new WP_Query( $args );
   ?>
    <div class="body_container">
   <?php

 if( $query->have_posts() ) :

  
  while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
    

     get_template_part('content-filter-mebel'); 

  endwhile;

 wp_reset_postdata();
 else :
   echo 'Записей не найдено';
     ?> </div>  <?php

 endif;
 ?> </div><?php
 die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_customfilter', 'posts_filters');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_customfilter', 'posts_filters');

the_posts_pagination() пихал уже везде, не хочет.

Ничего не понятно, что Вы там и куда пихали и в чем конкретная проблема, о каких атрибутах речь?
